# CURL Get download link from request and download file

Tags: json, api, curl, git-bash

I'm using conversocial API:
https://api-docs.conversocial.com/1.1/reports/

Using the sample from the documentation, as after all tweaks I receive this "output"

```
{
    "report": {
        "name": "dump", "generation_start_date": "2012-05-30T17:09:40",
        "url": "https://api.conversocial.com/v1.1/reports/5067",
        "date_from": "2012-05-21",
        "generated_by": {
            "url": "https://api.conversocial.com/v1.1/moderators/11599",
            "id": "11599"
        },
        "generated_date": "2012-05-30T17:09:41",
        "channel": {
            "url": "https://api.conversocial.com/v1.1/channels/387",
            "id": "387"
        },
        "date_to": "2012-05-28",
        "download": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/conversocial/reports/70c68360-1234/@twitter-from-may-21-2012-to-may-28-2012.zip",
        "id": "5067"
    }
}
```

Currently, I can sort this JSON output to download only and will receive this output

```
{
   "report" : {
      "download" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/conversocial/reports/70c68360-1234/@twitter-from-may-21-2012-to-may-28-2012.zip"
   }
}
```

Is it anyway of automating this process by using CURL, to make curl download this file?

To download I'm planning to use simple way as:

```
curl URL_LINK > FILEPATH/EXAMPLE.ZIP
```

Currently thinking is there is a way to replace URL_LINK with download link?? Or any other way, method, way around????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
curl $(curl -s https://httpbin.org/get | jq ".url" -r) > file
```

Just replace your `url` and the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) params, based in your json, thay may be:

```
jq ".report.download" -r
```

The `-r` will remove the double quotes `"`

The way it works is by using a [command substitution `$()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
$(curl -s https://httpbin.org/get | jq ".url" -r)
```

This will fetch you URL and extract the new URL from the returned JSON using `jq` the one later is passed to curl as an argument.

Comment: @DenisSineiko in multiple platforms, check the site: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Thank you , that's exactly what I was looking for